# Is REST the same as RESTful?

Tags: php, rest

I have to build my own REST web service which can provide output in either JSON or XML. However when i research online about creating a REST service, i eem to only come across tutorials on how to create a RESTful service? I have researched this on stack overflow and yes there are some answers, but none of them are quiet clear enough? Thanks

Comment: yes REST and RESTful are the same. Not more or less.

Comment: RESTful is just a way to describe a service that conforms to REST conventions. A REST-based API is said to be a RESTful API.

Comment: mh... as one concept they had in a company I worked for, REST services where REST appliance services but those we made to be "RESTful" where those with a stateless authorization. They had some with sessions but those open to public and third parties where to be implemented as a close in self atomic operation with the authorization of the request and finding if user roles allowed the execution. But as for my understanding of the terms they´re exactly the same as @Daan stated before.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they're the same thing. REST is the name of the architecture/protocol (Representational State Transfer), while RESTful is a made up derived adjective that describes a service which is built upon REST principles. It's a wordplay, nothing more.